# Igraph in R: how to change edge color based on edge attribute

Tags: r, colors, igraph

I am trying to generate an Igraph in R.
Now I want the edge color dependent on an edge attribute - department.
I cannot use ifelse statement because department values can be dynamic. I can find the number of unique departments, but I am not sure how to proceed further in creating different edge colors for different departments.

```
    department= unique(edges$department)
    department.count=length(department)
```

Example Code:

```
    gg <- graph.atlas(711)
    V(gg)$name=1:7
    gg=set_edge_attr(gg,"Department",E(gg)1:10],c("A","B","C","A","E","C","G","B","C","A"))
    E(gg)$label=E(gg)$Department
    plot(gg)
```

I want to have different colors for each edge, depending on values of department in edge. All 'A' departments in one color , all B department edges in another color , so on. 
Kindly help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should provide a small reproducible example when posting. That said, you should be able to do this by setting the color attribute of the edges:

```
E(testgraph)$color <- as.factor(edges$department)
```

Comment: I have added the code in question. I tried below code, I was able to generate different colors, but colors are very light and I was NOT able to differentiate the edges. F2 <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "black","orange"), bias = length(unique(edges$Department)), space = "rgb", interpolate = "linear") colCodes <- F2(length(unique(edges$Department))) edges_col <- sapply(edges$Department,function(x) colCodes[which(sort(unique(edges$Department)) == x)]) E(ig)$color <-edges_col –

Comment: Adding the line `E(gg)$color <- as.factor(E(gg)$Department)` before your plot statement should do the trick.